# Disable servlet filters for unit tests

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mvc, servlet-filters

In Spring Boot application I am unit testing controllers using `MockMvc`. I have a servlet filter that needs to run for every request but I want to ignore it when running unit tests and making requests through `MockMvc`.

The reason is that my filter is a `@Component` and it has got another bean `@Autowired` (call it `theBean`) and when the unit tests run some of them fail because if `theBean` is not in the context and some of them pass because the controllers also use `theBean`

What I am looking to do is to disable the servlet filter when it's running the MVC tests using `MockMvc`, any ideas?

Answer (score 6):

If you are fine with an option that disables all the filters then you can pass the parameter addFilters as false to the @AutoConfigureMockMvc.
Like this:

```
@AutoConfigureMockMvc(addFilters = false)
public class ControllerTest {

    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mockMvc;
}
```

You can find the related documentation here:

https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/test/autoconfigure/web/servlet/AutoConfigureMockMvc.html#addFilters--

Answer (score 2):

you can use condition bean expression for your filter class

```
`@ConditionalOnProperty(name = "spring.profile.test", matchIfMissing = true)`
```

set spring.profile.test as true in property file